# How to configure HK2 for using Guice @Inject annotation from package com.google.inject?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, hk2

I have a project based on Jersey 2, Guice 3.0 technologies.
Since Jersey 2 framework uses HK2 I had to configure HK2-Guice bridge.

JerseyGuiceServletContextListener:

```
package com.example.core;

import com.google.inject.Guice;
import com.google.inject.Injector;
import com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceServletContextListener;
import com.google.inject.servlet.ServletModule;
public class JerseyGuiceServletContextListener extends GuiceServletContextListener {

    static Injector injector;

    @Override
    protected Injector getInjector() {
        injector = Guice.createInjector(new ServletModule() {
            @Override
            protected void configureServlets() {
                //some code here
            }
        });
        return injector;
    }
}
```

JerseyConfiguration:

```
package com.example.core;

import org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocator;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerProperties;
import org.jvnet.hk2.guice.bridge.api.GuiceBridge;
import org.jvnet.hk2.guice.bridge.api.GuiceIntoHK2Bridge;

import javax.inject.Inject;
//...

class JerseyConfiguration extends ResourceConfig {

    @Inject
    public JerseyConfiguration(ServiceLocator serviceLocator) {
        packages("com.example.ws");

        GuiceBridge.getGuiceBridge().initializeGuiceBridge(serviceLocator);
        GuiceIntoHK2Bridge guiceBridge = serviceLocator.getService(GuiceIntoHK2Bridge.class);
        guiceBridge.bridgeGuiceInjector(JerseyGuiceServletContextListener.injector);
    }
}
```

All works fine if I inject some class properties using `javax.inject.Inject` annotation. But when I use `com.google.inject.Inject` annotation my class properties aren't injected & I get NullPointerException when I tried to use this property.

How can I use `com.google.inject.Inject` annotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would create your own InjectionResolver for com.google.inject.Inject.  The following example would create one that works *exactly* like javax.inject.Inject.  However there are probably subtle differences between google Inject and javax Inject which are NOT captured in the below implementation.  If you rely on any of those differences you may need to get smarter in your implementation of the InjectionResolver.  You would then also have to register your InjectionResolver in some Jersey bind call or another.  Here is the basic implementation:

```
@Singleton
public class GuiceInjectResolver implements InjectionResolver<com.google.inject.Inject> {
    @Inject @Named(InjectionResolver.SYSTEM_RESOLVER_NAME)
    private InjectionResolver<Inject> systemResolver;

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.glassfish.hk2.api.InjectionResolver#resolve(org.glassfish.hk2.api.Injectee, org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceHandle)
     */
    @Override
    public Object resolve(Injectee injectee, ServiceHandle<?> root) {
        return systemResolver.resolve(injectee, root);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.glassfish.hk2.api.InjectionResolver#isConstructorParameterIndicator()
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isConstructorParameterIndicator() {
        return true;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.glassfish.hk2.api.InjectionResolver#isMethodParameterIndicator()
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isMethodParameterIndicator() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: More information about InjectionResolvers can be found here: https://hk2.java.net/2.5.0-b08/extensibility.html#Custom_Injection_Resolvers

Comment: But as I have defined the bridge of hk2-guice - I can't use only google's annotations as they are? Without InjectionResolver impl.

Comment: The bridge only allows Guice to see HK2 services and HK2 to see Guice services.  The InjectionResolver will allow you to use Guice annotations in services created by HK2 (which must be what is happening in your example)